# C++ Parsing TimeZone From Date String

Tags: c++

Hello I have the following date that I am consuming from an api

```
string sToParse = "2020-04-17T09:30:00-04:00";
```

which should be in human form "Friday, April 17, 2020 08:30:00" central time
or epoch of 1587130200

however this code

```
cout << "raw: " << sToParse << endl;
static const std::string dateTimeFormat { "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z" };
istringstream ss{ sToParse };
tm dt;
ss >> get_time(&dt, dateTimeFormat.c_str());
cout << mktime(&dt) << endl;
```

Gives me an epoch of 1587137400 which is a human format of "Friday, April 17, 2020 10:30:00 AM" which is two hours difference.  How do i get the %Z to process the timezone appropriately?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: Note: `get_time` doesn't do `%z` or `%Z` so `tm_isdst` is not written to and needs to be set explicitly for use with functions such as `mktime`.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply.  Is there another function I should be using in order to accommodate the time zone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++20 will do this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    string sToParse = "2020-04-17T09:30:00-04:00";
    cout << "raw: " << sToParse << endl;
    static const std::string dateTimeFormat { "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" };
    istringstream ss{ sToParse };
    sys_seconds dt;
    ss >> parse(dateTimeFormat, dt);
    cout << dt << '\n';
    cout << dt.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2020-04-17 13:30:00
1587130200s
```

This gets the "epoch time" you're looking for.  The big difference is the use of `%z` instead of `%Z`.  `%z` is the command for parsing the offset.  `%Z` parses time zone abbreviation.

This doesn't get the "human time" you're expecting. The time printed out above is UTC.  This is clearly correct on inspection:  13:30:00 is 4 hours after 09:30:00.

If you are wanting local time, it would be 2020-04-17 09:30:00, same as the input.  To come up with 08:30:00 would require more information than you are providing above (e.g. output in some time zone other than that which has a UTC offset of -4h at this local time).

Also it is in general not possible to go from a UTC offset to a time zone name or abbreviation because more than one time zone will generally have the same UTC offset at any point in time.

If the C++20 `<chrono>` header isn't available for you (to the best of my knowledge it is not yet available anywhere), you can use a [free, open-source preview of C+++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  For this problem, one only needs the header-only "date.h" from this [preview](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  And everything is in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`.  It would look like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    string sToParse = "2020-04-17T09:30:00-04:00";
    cout << "raw: " << sToParse << endl;
    static const std::string dateTimeFormat { "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" };
    istringstream ss{ sToParse };
    sys_seconds dt;
    ss >> parse(dateTimeFormat, dt);
    cout << dt << '\n';
    cout << dt.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

### Update

With the new knowledge that the "expected human form" of the time should be US Central Time ("America/Chicago" in IANA terms), I'm updating the example code to show how that can be handled.

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    string sToParse = "2020-04-17T09:30:00-04:00";
    cout << "raw: " << sToParse << endl;
    static const std::string dateTimeFormat { "%FT%T%z" };
    istringstream ss{ sToParse };

    sys_seconds utc;
    ss >> parse(dateTimeFormat, utc);
    zoned_seconds cst{"America/Chicago", utc};

    cout << utc.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    cout << format("%F %T %Z\n", utc);
    cout << format("%F %T %Z\n", cst);
}
```

A few changes above:

- A new header is required to handle the time zone issues: "tz.h" (only in the C++20 preview library, not in C++20).
- For parsing I've substituted "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" for "%FT%T%z".  These are equivalent.  `%F` is just shorthand for `%Y-%m-%d` and `%T` is shorthand for `%H:%M:%S`.  This change is not required.
- I've renamed `dt` to `utc` to emphasize that this variable holds a UTC time point.  This change is not required.
- The new line constructs a `zoned_time` (with `seconds` precision) with the desired destination time zone ("America/Chicago"), and the UTC time point.  This creates an object that knows all about the local time at this time point and in this time zone.
- Then everything is printed out using the `date::format` function and the formatting string `"%F %T %Z"`.  `%Z` is used to output the time zone abbreviation to make the output more readable.  In C++20, this will be `std::format`, and the formatting string will be `"{:%F %T %Z}"`.

The output is now:

```
raw: 2020-04-17T09:30:00-04:00
1587130200s
2020-04-17 13:30:00 UTC
2020-04-17 08:30:00 CDT
```

If your computer's current time zone setting happens to be US Central, then the line that constructs `zoned_seconds` can also look like:

```
    zoned_seconds cst{current_zone(), utc};
```

Or conversely, you can use this line to find the local time at `utc` in *any* time zone which your computer is set to.

Note that whether the time zone is specified with a name such as `"America/Chicago"`, or with `current_zone()`, *any* changes of UTC offset within the specified time zone (such as daylight saving time) *will* be correctly taken into account.

With the [preview C+++20 library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), the use of the header `"tz.h"` is not header-only.  It requires a single source file, `tz.cpp`.  [Here are instructions on how to compile it.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)  But if you are using a fully conforming C++20 `<chrono>`, then the above will just work by removing `#include "date/tz.h"`, `using namespace date;`, and adjusting the formatting string as noted in the 5<sup>*th*</sup> bullet above.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the comment.  The time that is given to me is EST and the api returns 2020-04-17T09:30:00-04:00 which is 8:30AM my time (CST).  when i convert 1587130200 to 'human' then I get the expected 8:30AM.  THANK YOU SO MUCH for helping me!!!